# Merge account holding custom assets of same issuerer

Tags: assets

I have a requirement of merging two different custom assets hold by same issuer, is this requirement possible? if yes please explain me how to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you are asking. Do you want to merge accounts? Hold two different assets in a single account? Merge two different assets into a new kind of asset?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, right out of the book.

https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#account-merge

`Merge` only works on an account *without* any trust lines, data entries, or offers.

You need to remove all of these before you merge.

Answer (score 0):

Merge account is **only allowed when you don't have any subentries on your account** *(i.e. trustlines, data entries, offers)*.

You can easily achieve what you want using a single **transaction** with the following **sequence of operations (ordered)**:

1. send all assets from the first account to the account you want it merged into
2. remove trustline from the account you are merging from
3. merge account operation